# Mapping fields of a message in ros1_bridge

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-humble, rosbridge, ros-noetic, ros-foxy

I am trying to bridge ROS1 and ROS2.

- I have msgs pkgs in ROS1 and ROS2.
- All the workspaces are sourced.
- A message definition from my custom defined msgs package has a nested message declaration from another custom defined msgs pkg.
- I have specified the package and messages in the `message_map.yaml`

When I build ros1_bridge I get the following error,

```
1 mappings can not be generated due to missing dependencies:
- <ros1-pkg-name>/<ros1-msg-name> <-> <ros2_pkg_name>/<ros2-msg-name>
   - <ros2-pkg-name>/HeaderStamp
```

Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Related question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/384193/how-to-map-a-ros1-field-to-a-ros2-self-defined-structure-in-mapping_rules-while-using-ros_bridge/)